# Does br element interfer while traversing xml to output an element? Or what else might be wrong in this example?

Tags: xslt, attributes

The xml I fetch data from:

```
<item>
  <title>NGC 1672: Barred Spiral Galaxy from Hubble  </title>
  <link>http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html</link>
  <description>
    <p>
      <a href="http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html">
        <img src="http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/calendar/S_160913.jpg" align="left" alt="Many spiral galaxies have bars across their centers.  " border="0" />
        </a> Many spiral galaxies have bars across their centers.  
    </p>
    <br clear="all"/>
  </description>
</item>
```

I'm interested in listing out the src attribute from the img element, but ends up with nothing.

Testing listing out the entire description element works as expected:
Code:

```
<xsl:template match="description">  
    <div class="pictureoftoday">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Result/output:

```
<p>
<a href="http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html">
<img src="http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/calendar/S_160915.jpg" align="left" alt="Retrograde Mars and Saturn" border="0" />
</a> Retrograde Mars and Saturn
</p>
<br clear="all"/>
```

Trying to list out from p, a, img doesnt work and therefore I'm certainly not get the @src from img.

For instance:

```
<xsl:template match="description">  
    <div class="pictureoftoday">
      <xsl:value-of select="img/@src"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

doesn't work, neither

```
<xsl:template match="description">  
    <div class="pictureoftoday">
      <xsl:value-of select="p/a/img/@src"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

I've tried every option.
Btw, I know how to extract the image from it after, but first I should be able to fetch the image link anyway...

Anyone see the solution?

I was beginning to think that

```
<br clear="all"/>
```

from the xml is ruining everything...

Kind regards
Ole

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced from the code you have posted. Please post a complete and reproducible example - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing, because the codes you have posted do **not** produce the results you claim.

---

The actual result of:

```
<xsl:template match="description">  
    <div class="pictureoftoday">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

is:

```
<div class="pictureoftoday"> Many spiral galaxies have bars across their centers.  
    </div>
```

that is a `div` element containing the string-value of the context `description` node - which is computed as a concatenation of all its descendant *text* nodes (attributes are not included in this).

---

And the actual result of:

```
<xsl:template match="description">  
    <div class="pictureoftoday">
      <xsl:value-of select="p/a/img/@src"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

is:

```
<div class="pictureoftoday">http://antwrp.gsfc.nasa.gov/apod/calendar/S_160913.jpg</div>
```

which I believe satisfies your requirement:

> I'm interested in listing out the src attribute from the img element

---

The `br` element has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is exactly what I thought was the right one, and my question is certainly confusing then. Your post helps me clarify.

However, I still got the outputs which I posted in my question, even if I expected exactly the outputs you are suggesting.

It leads me to think I might be searching the wrong place. I guess I just dive in investigating what is going on deeper in the SharePoint xml webpart I use for displaying that image.

I let you know when/if I find the solution. Any further suggestions will also be very welcome.

Ole E

Comment: **1.** Do you have any other templates in your stylesheet - such as the *identity transform* template? **2.** Is it possible that the `description` element in your XML is in a *namespace*? Together, these two would produce the results you report.

Comment: A simple test you can perform is making your template `<xsl:template match="description">TEST</xsl:template>`. If you don't see the text "TEST" in the output, then your template is not executed: either because it's not matching anything in the input, or because it's not being applied to the `description` element.

Comment: The suggested TEST works perfectly - I'll keep on searching

Comment: Setting

    disable-output-escaping="yes"

made it work...

Thanks for your efforts :)